# Singly linked list: wrong output after adding elements

Tags: java

I've implemented a singly linked list and I followed the Java documentation for the method. So I add 4 elements to the list(4 strings: A, B, C and D) and when I go through the list it only types out the last 3, starting from B that is. It skips the first element. Does it actually skip it or is the "head" just not refering to the next element?

```
@Override
public void add(E element) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element, null);
    if(head == null){
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        tail.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

EDIT: how I print out the elements:

```
 MyList<String> list = new MyList<String>();

    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");

        for(String s : list){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

EDIT 2:

```
public class MyList<E> implements SingleList<E> {

private Node<E> head;
private Node<E> tail;
private int size;

public MyList() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.size = 0;
}

private static class Node<E> {
    E data;
    Node<E> next;

    public Node(E data, Node<E> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

private class iter implements Iterator<E> {
    Node<E> previous;
    Node<E> currentElement;

    public iter(){
        previous = null;
        currentElement = head;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return currentElement.next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        if(! hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements");
        }
        previous = currentElement;
        currentElement = currentElement.next;
        return currentElement.data;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(){
        Node<E> remove = currentElement;
        currentElement = currentElement.next;
        previous.setNext(currentElement);
    }
}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new iter();
}

@Override
public void add(E element) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element, null);
    if(head == null){
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        tail.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your printing function? Your add method looks fine.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, check the edit.

Comment: I honestly can't see an error here.  Can you provide the full class implementation including the first line where we can see which interface/class you are implementing/extending?

Comment: Check the second edit, I'm implemeting a simplified list interface with the standard methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterator is wrong skips the first elements.

Notice that when you create the iterator, you set the currentValue to the head.  But in the `next()`, you set current value to the next element, and then return that next element, instead of returning the current element.  This causes the first value to be skipped, because the first call to `next()` will return `head.next` instead of the head.

Comment: Oh that actually worked, now the first element gets written out BUT another problem occured. Now the LAST element doesn't get typed out, what's up with that? The issue seems to be with my iterator..

Comment: I switched the hasNext method from currentElement.next != null to currentElement != null.. It seems to work but will it cause issues later? Shouldnt hasNext check if the element AFTER the one im on now be null or not?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

Are you sure you don't have an error in your printing function that is not using the first element properly?

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: I would beg to differ; it clarifies that his code has no issue here and tells him where the problem is.  If he feels that is not enough and cannot find the error in his printing function he can amend the question.

Comment: for(String s : list){ System.out.println(s); }

 I'm using a for loop to go through the list.

Answer (score 0):

Like puhlen told you, there was a problem with your next() method.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) points that:

> `next()` Returns the next element in the iteration.

So, if you are iterating through a list, the first node in the list should be return. Then second node and so on...

```
public E next() {
    if(! hasNext()){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements");
    }
    Node<E> actualNode = currentElement; //Save current node
    currentElement = currentElement.next; // Move to the next node
    return actualNode.data; //return the current node element
}
```

> `hasNext()` Returns true if the iteration has more elements.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return currentElement.next != null;
}
```